# Possible to resize or move just the background-color of an element?

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, background-position

I have a `div` with a css rule that has a `background-color` defined.  Wondering if it is possible to just change the position or the size of the background color (NOT anything within the `div` element?  If so, can anyone help me to do this?

HTML Structure

```
<div class="col-6 no-padding blue-box-0 blue-box-b blue-box-right">
<img src="/media/2680859/meet-plannerresources.jpg" alt="">
<h3>Professional Planner Resources</h3>
<p>Our award-winning Convention Services team is eager to assist you in your planning efforts from beginning to end.</p>
<h4>Meeting Planners</h4>
<a href="/meet/planning-tools/" class="red-arrow"></a>
<a class="bluehitbox" href="/meet/planning-tools/"></a>
</div>
```

It renders a box like model, all I want to do is change the background size or position (top position I suppose if parent has a `overflow:hidden` this could work), and drop it down to the bottom of the div element so that it is about 70 pixels in height.  Is this possible to do in CSS or even jQuery?

Image attached below of how the background-color (which is an rgba value of blue on the image) should be scaled or positioned to a 70 pixel height from the bottom of the box.  Anyway possible way to do this on mousing over the actual box?

[image: Need Image to drop down]

Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? please?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, but the background-position is only for images. What you can do, is "move it" by adding a border or a margin.

Comment: The Problem is the `z-index`, so if I apply jQuery to it, on hover, it will slide down and up, cause I am no longer over the element with a background color... however, if it is set up like I have it, I will always be over that element because it is the parent element `blue-box-0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce another div inside of this div with the following css properties set:

> `.className{
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: -1;
>   }`

`position: absolute` would remove this div from the normal flow, and the elements following it would be placed under it. This is where `z-index` comes into picture, set it to `-1` or a value less than that of other elements in its place. That would make the other elements render on top of your div.

check this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzsrA/1/)** for reference

Comment: The Problem is the `z-index`, so if I apply jQuery to it, on hover, it will slide down and up while my mouse is still on the element, cause I am no longer over the element with a background color... however, if it is set up like I have it, I will always be over that element because it is the parent element `blue-box-0`

Comment: In your `:hover` definition make sure you have `z-index` set.

Comment: Thanks, had to play with the `z-index` values a bunch, but got it working using this approach.  Cheers :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.. all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to your question, no you cannot change just the position or size of just the background color, as it will always fill the entire .

In order to 'move' it down or up, you can use `margin-top` to move the div 'down' and hence the background color.

Comment: I can move the div down just fine, the problem now is, how to keep it down when my mouse is no longer over the element with a `background-color`?  Suppose I will need multiple selectors for the `hover` event?